# Is it better to do multiple selects from multiple tables or 1 select of all your data from all the tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have multiple tables that data can be queried from with joins.

In regards to database performance:

Should I run multiple selects from multiple tables for the required data?

or

Should I write 1 select that uses a bunch of Joins to select the required data from all the tables at once?

EDIT:

The where clause I will be using for the select contains Indexed fields of the tables. It sounds like because of this, it will be faster to use 1 select statement with many joins. I will however still test the performance difference between the 2.

Thanks for all the great answers.

Comment: In general I'd go with a single `SELECT` statement.  Relational databases are _very_ good at optimizing the query execution.  If in doubt, you can always profile both approaches and see which performs better.

Comment: I have never profiled a database. How do I test for performance?

Comment: That entirely depends on what database you're using.  For MS SQL Server, for example, you can check the query execution plan in SQL Management Studio to get a detailed analysis of every step of the query.  In MySQL you can use the `EXPLAIN` keyword to analyze a query execution plan.  To test performance in general, you can write a small application that performs both options many, many times and gets an average timespan for each execution.

Comment: @David I am using MS SQL Server. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Mausimo: In that case you have one of the greatest developer debugging tools available for query analysis :)  In SQL Management Studio, when you open a new query window, one of the menu items at the top is "Include Actual Execution Plan" (or Ctrl-M).  Enable that, take a look at the output, and enter a brave new world of SQL debugging :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write one query with joins.  If you are concerned about performance there are a number of options including:

- Creating indexes that will help the performance of your selects
- Create a persisted denormalized form of the data you want so you can query one table.  This would most likely be an indexed view or another table.

Answer (score 4):

This can be one of those, well-gee-it-depends, but generally if you're writing straight SQL do one query--especially since the joins might limit some of the data you get back.

There is a good chance if you do multiple point queries for one record in each table, if you're using the primary key of the table for lookup, the connection cost for each query will be more costly than the actual query.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how the tables are joined. If you do a cross-product of all tables than it would be better to do individual selects. However if your tables are properly indexed and well thought out one query with multiple selects would be more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

If you have proper indexes on your tables, you might be better off with the JOINs but they are often the cause of bottlenecks.  Instead of multiple selects, you might look at ways to de-normalize your data.  It is far less "expensive" when a user performs an operation to update a count or timestamp in multiple tables which prevents you from having to join those tables.

The best tool I find for performance tuning of queries is using EXPLAIN.  You type EXPLAIN before the query and you can see how many rows are scanned.  Your goal is the lower the number the better, which means your indexes are working.  The other thing is when creating indexes, use compound indexes on multiple fields and order them left to right in the order they appear in the WHERE clause.

For example you have 10,000 rows in sometable:

```
SELECT id, name, description, status FROM sometable WHERE name LIKE '%someName%' AND status = 'Active';
```

You could type EXPLAIN before the query and it might return 10,000 as number of rows scanned to match.  You then create a compound index:

```
ALTER TABLE sometable ADD INDEX idx_st_search (name, status);
```

You then perform the EXPLAIN on table again and it might return 1 as number of rows scanned and performance significantly improved.

Comment: Of course, breaking normalization has its downsides too - your control over your transactions has to be more refined. Also, index column order is usually irrelevant to how they appear in the where clause in most modern DBMS's - they'll parse the query and optimize the best index to use.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your Table designs.

Most of times one large query is better but be sure to

- Use primary keys in where clause as much as you can for joins.
- use indexed fields or make indexes for fields which are used in where clauses.